# Why Json into db?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Why some companies today are using the approach to save json objects into a DB instead creating new table and store data in it?

What are the real advantages?

Comment: I guess you should ask the companies why they are doing this.

Comment: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my company we use `JSONB` in Postgres database because of the need to store dynamic column data which will not fit into a traditional relational model since number of columns would grow all the time or we would have to have columns without meanings and assign those meanings based on some other columns that would identify row values which in my opinion calls to heaven for forgiveness.

I find this approach also better than the typical [Entity-attribute-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) model for performing lookups and generally understanding the data. This opinion is also shared by analysts at my company who have also been working with EAV model in the past.

Greater percentage of our data fits into relational schema design and since there was a need for NoSQL approach which isn't actually the majority of data (nor is it a completely schema-less table) we decided to stick with Postgres instead of complicating things and moving small percentage of our data to different (example: document) database.

Since 9.2 a lot has changed and Postgres offers a great support for optimised searches within json and jsonb columns.

Answer (score 1):

JSON is used when there are chances of dynamic keys.

e.g.: You are having a listing page with 4 columns- `sr, name, age, amount`. Assume there is a multi column sorting functionality on this page and user wants to save his custom order. In this case I can easily store a json as `sr => DESC, age => ASC` in sort_order field in relevant table.

In large systems, adding a new field to table would require downtime or would essentially lock the table while adding the field. In those cases, we can add the new key to json field instead of a new column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON in case of ,
* You have deep schema hierarchies
* In case of storing images, audio and video files
* Especially while working with NoSQL
* If you are using relational structures, you can use RDBMS

Comment: Storing images as JSON is a **really** bad choice

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I would store JSON in a database is for historical lists. Let's say several users each have a friends list in the form of JSON, and it would be nice to keep a record of each time the friends list changes for each user.